# IE Javascript Error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've narrowed my error down to the code below.  For the sake of the example I'm appending text into the first div within a fragment.  This seems to work on all browsers but IE doesn't seem to like it.

It looks like the issue is specifically the `[0] index`?  Though I could be wrong.

```
<div id="hello"></div>

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        div = document.createElement('div');

    frag.appendChild(div);
    frag.children[0].innerHTML = "Hello";

    document.getElementById('hello').append(div);
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/d758ma27/

The expected output is `#hello` would now contain the text "Hello" - Which it does, just not in IE.  Any help would be great, this has well and truly confused me!

Currently testing on IE10 and below.

Comment: Maybe IE does not support children https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children#Browser_compatibility on a document fragment

Comment: The error means that `frag.children` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy any ideas on what I need to do to resolve this?  Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the MDN link in the first comment? It's just not supported on document fragments in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'd fix it.

```js
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        div = document.createElement('div');
    
frag.appendChild(div);
frag.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "Hello";

document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Note that I'm using `childNodes` rather than `children` to access the elements in the document fragment, and `appendChild` rather than `append` to add the new div element to the DOM in the document.